# Authenticate login via Fetch API

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api

I am trying to connect to some service via API, the first step is to authenticate login to the service, below is my current code:

```
fetch("https://api.connectservice.com/login",
{
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    method: "POST",
    body: {
  "username": "usermn",
  "password": "m$p@ss"
}
}).then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) throw new Error(response.status);
  return response.json();
})
```

When i run the above code i get the error:

```
(index):1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

I will appreciate your help figuring it out

Comment: Hi shokis, Is there a reason your body key is within ""

Comment: @henrypf no apparent reason. might be the issue?

Comment: give my code below a go and edit it to help solve your issue  :)

Comment: Try taking out the "" from the left hand side of the body pairs also

Comment: can you upload your backend code also ?

Comment: Sure, let me try it

Comment: any luck trying ?

Comment: No luck still unfortunately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208271/discussion-between-shokis-and-henry-pf).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of one of my requests

```
const data = {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password,
        date
      };
      console.log(date);

      fetch("/login", {
        method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
        headers: {
          Accept: "application/json,",
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      })
```

Try passing your data similar to this